# How does the view property call the viewDidLoad function?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xctest

I'm having trouble comprehending how the view property of `UIViewController` calls the `viewDidLoad()` method.  It doesn't make sense to but I'd like to understand what's happening under the hood.  I'm sure this is well explained in the Swift programming guide or maybe even in Apple's reference guide for `UIViewController` but right now is too verbose to quite understand. If it is explained in the Swift programming guide, I'm not sure of the correct term to research it further or how this process works.  Maybe computed property?  However from what I've learned about computed properties is that a computed property does some kind of logic in order to set its variable to a new value or maybe even the initial value.   What's troubling me is understanding the concept of how a property calls a function in it's class?  Most specifically the view property in `UIViewController` that calls the `viewDidLoad` method.

Here is my code that helped me stumble across this:

```
func test_OnViewDidLoad_tableViewIsSet(){

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController")

        let sut = viewController as! ItemListViewController

        _ = sut.view

        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.tableView)

    }
```

Here is my subclassed UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ItemListViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableView: UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView = UITableView()
    }

}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `UIViewController view`, `UIViewController loadView`. and `UIViewController viewDidLoad` and you will know how it all works.

Comment: FYI - your question has nothing to do with Swift. It's a function of the `UIViewController` class, regardless of the language used.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you and I understand what you're saying however after reading the reference it states "If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view controller automatically calls the loadView() method and returns the resulting view.".  I'm curious as to what do I research to learn how Apple made this possible?  What do I search for online to learn how a function is called just by accessing one of its properties?

Comment: It's simply the implementation of the "getter" method for the property. There's no magic. Many, many properties (including any you might right), can do the same thing.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you and I understand we can't see Apple's API's per say but you're saying that I can create a getter method that will return a function?  i.e.: var x: UIView {
    get {
        return viewDidLoad()
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of what is likely happening (we don't have the source code to `UIViewController` (which is written in Objective-C)).

```
class UIViewController: UIResponder {
    private var _view: UIView!

    var view: UIView! {
        get {
            if _view == nil {
                loadView()
                if _view != nil {
                    viewDidLoad()
                }
            }

            return _view
        }
        set {
            _view = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is more to it but this should give you a rough idea how `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` end up being called simply by accessing the `view` property.

Comment: That's so interesting and exactly what I needed to see in order to grasp this concept fully with the view property.  It makes more sense and now I'm more confident in the possibilities by using getter/setter properties.  Much much appreciative.